# json youtube api

Tags: javascript, json, youtube

i want to get youtube videos

code example

```
var youstinky = {

      getYoutubeData : function(){
        $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json",function(data){
         this.x = data.feed.entry.map(function(dat){
           return {
            'link' : dat.link[0].href,
            'name' : dat.title.$t
           };
         });
        });
      }

  };

$(document).ready(function(){
youstinky.getYoutubeData();
});
```

i not able to get this.x variable outside youstinky object,

how can can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Just make x a global variable.

```
window.x = // Your code
```

Instead of...

```
this.x = // Your code
```

Then you can access x anywhere by just saying "x" or "window.x" if you want to be more specific.

Comment: i know window variable method, but why dont working object variable method? youstinky.x ?

Comment: In $.getJSON you make an anonymous function which acts as a callback. In all likelyhood the "this" in that callback doesn't refer to youstinky, it refers to something else, so when you're setting this.x it's setting x on something else. A way to fix this would be to assign "this" to a variable outside of the callback. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/EtH8A/.

Comment: i understand, so solution is only window variable method?

Comment: No, the fiddle I linked provides an alternate. When I set stink.x, I'm also setting youstinky.x, try it in your own code.

Comment: Please exam the code in http://jsfiddle.net/EtH8A/, it has some key differences from yours.